# PHP Security - Combining functionality of strip_tags(); & htmlspecialchars();

Tags: php, html, security, xss

I want my forum users to be able to insert links and other allowed tags. For example I would like the following HTML in a post to display as the writer intended (i.e. as a functioning link):

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow">A page</a>
```

However, I want to maintain some level of security and have been reading up on [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)() and [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)(). I thought at first that I could use strip_tags with something like:

```
<?php $link_string = strip_tags($link_string, '<a>'); ?>
```

But strip_tags doesn't protect me like htmlspecialchars does if I understand correctly. For example, incorrect HTML code using special characters can leave me vulnerable. And so can the style and onmouseover attributes for the link tag.

What is the most ***simple*** solution to allow the above link in the post while cleaning out potentially harmful characters and code? Is there anyway I can combine these two PHP functions to do this in a ***simple*** manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much need to use a full-featured HTML parser and sanitizer. The overall workflow is the following:

1. The user enters their HTML
2. You parse it with the parser
3. You sanitize what was parsed by keeping only what you want (`<a>` tags, but be wary of `onclick` attributes, and similar).

---

You could look into [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org), and if it doesn't fit your needs, the HTML Purifier website has a [comparison of other PHP sanitizers](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison). I believe the default HTML Purifier configuration will retain links.

---

Obligatory reference: [please refrain from using regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: When you say be wary of those attributes, how do I execute the weariness?

Comment: You just need to check the documentation to verify that the default configuration strip them! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using stripslashes(), and if this is going to a database, also mysql_real_escape_string().

```
// without SQL.
       function safeData($data) {
        $returnData = stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($data))));
        return $returnData; 
    }

// with SQL.
       function safeDataMySQL($data) {
        $returnData = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(trim($data)))));
        return $returnData; 
    }
```

Comment: Although this is true, the question is about XSS attacks, not SQL injection.

Comment: Also i would not recommend using these functions,  XSS and SQL Injection are still possible.